# Ajustar o layout do Form de acordo com a resolução do monitor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resolução-de-tela

Fiz um formulário em *fullScreen*, onde o monitor que eu uso tem 23'' polegadas.

Porém onde será implantado a funcionalidade, utilizam 19". Quando executei, o `Form` não ficou do tamanho do monitor menor, e ficou cortado alguns componentes.

Existe alguma forma de deixar responsivo de acordo com o monitor ou terei que editar o tamanho dos componentes?

#### 23"

[image: 23"]

#### 19"

[image: 19"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazer um form responsivo não é dificil. Existe várias alternativas que podem ser usadas (TabbledLayoutPanel, Propriedades Anchor e Dock dos controles, FlowLayoutPanel e a junção de todos inclusive).

Vou dar um pequeno exemplo utilizando a propriedade Anchor dos controles.
Veja abaixo:

[image: Minha Busca]

A propriedade Anchor indica em quais direções o controle ficará ancorado. Por exemplo, se a ancora do meu controle é "Top, Right" isso indica que o meu controle sempre manterá a mesma distância em relação a borda Superior e Direita do controle pai do mesmo.
Todo controle por padrão vem com a propriedade Anchor definida como "Top,Left", ou seja, ele vai manter a distância relativa acima e a esquerda.

[image: Anchor]

Seguindo nosso exemplo vamos fazer com que o botão "Ir" fique sempre no canto direito superior do formulário. Para isso vamos alterar a propriedade Achor para "Top, Rigth". Feito isso, ao redimensionar o formulário, o mesmo assumirá o comportamento abaixo:

[image: Botão]

O próximo passo é fazer com que o text box mantenha sempre a mesma distância tanto a esquerda quanto a direita. Para isso, vamos usar a ancora "Top, Left, Rigth":

[image: Campo Texto]

Por fim, queremos que a grid abaixo mantenha a mesma distância em todas as direções. Para isso, basta definir Anchor como "Top, Bottom, Left, Rigth".

[image: Janela full]

Espero que esse pequeno exemplo ajude no seu objetivo. Vale notar que essa propriedade Achor poder ser definida via código conforme abaixo onde defino "Botton, Right" em um campo de texto:

```
 textBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

Lembrando que a ancora (Anchor) sempre é relativa ao controle pai. No exemplo abaixo eu defini a ancora para todas as direções no botão "Ola" mas como esse botão tem como pai um panel, ele seguirá o comportamento do pai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

É assim mesmo. WinForms tem tudo fixo. E a maioria deixa deste jeito.

É possível usar um [painel de fluxo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-flowlayoutpanel?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para ajudar a ficar mais "responsivo" (coloquei pra tirar sarro, não gosto do uso dela dessa palavra pra isso). Mas se não souber fazer direito o resultado pode ficar muito pior e muitas vezes nem perceber. Mas tem que mudar alguns controles para se adaptar ao tamanho do painel.

Eu sei que tem bibliotecas que ajudam um pouco mais, mas nunca as usei e me parece que elas pesam e algumas são cheias de problemas.

Claro que também pode montar um esquema próprio, mas dá muito trabalho fazer certo no WinForms, e tende a dar muito errado se não dominar o assunto.

E sim, tem gente que prefere fazer dois *layouts* diferentes. Não que precise de dois códigos, é só parametrizar as posições e tamanho dos controles. Claro, como tudo, precisa saber fazer.

Com WPF dá para fazer um pouco melhor. Na verdade, ele pode fazer até mais interessante que é trabalhar com *\zoom* para preencher tudo (não que seja útil em todos os casos).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).